# How do I perform multiple modifications and save a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

The user hits on Company->Users href link and assuming it shows 3 users for a certain company.

I would want to set `user.age` (an integer) for all the users and press save. How do I do this in my controller / view code?

We usually have an Edit link against each User to modify its details, but I would like to set age information for all users.

Comment: Maybe you can try: `@company.users.update_all(age: an_integer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) to submit to an arbitrary controller action set up specifically for editing multiple users (not one of your user scaffold methods). Then, add one [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) tag per user inside of the form you created, each with a field for the age attribute. When submitted, you can simply iterate over the user params in the controller to manipulate your users.